# Should I be putting paywalled URLs in a sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have a subscription site, with a paywall on about 1/3 of content, and a login wall on about 1/3 of the content.

I am looking for best practices on whether or not to include these URLs to Google Search Console. I feel like it's probably not best practice, because Google can't actually search them and I feel it might lead to me being penalized? But also, what if I temporarily change the paywall status? Would I then need to update my sitemap.xml?

Sorry if this is a super basic question, I just haven't seen it answered anywhere

Comment: Are you using Google's flexible sampling policy to allow your paywall content to be indexed and viewed in a limited way for free by users?

Comment: No, but I will probably move to that eventually

Answer (score 3):

There is no evidence right now that Google or other reputable search engines penalize paywalled content. However, paywalls will affect how content is crawled and whether it's indexed.

First, [a thread on this topic](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/62557031/why-doesn-t-google-penalize-sites-for-using-pay-walls?hl=en), from the Search Console Help pages, with the relevant part here: "Google penalizes what is against its guidelines and the conversion/monetization model which a website uses is not something against their guidelines." So don't worry about penalties.

Second, sitemaps aren't as crucial as they used to be. A good website with an excellent site structure can technically only have the home page and a few other top level pages listed in the sitemap, and search engines will crawl much or all of the deep linked content and index it, provided those pages aren't noindexed.

For that reason, you need to be careful with what you paywall. If your content is three levels deep, but you've paywalled the second level, then search engines will potentially fail to crawl and index not just the paywalled level (expected) but also the third one (unintended?). So there's a good reason to keep all of those pages from all three levels in the sitemap.

Especially if you plan on removing the paywall some of the time, you'll go crazy changing your sitemap each time. So since there's no penalty, it's safe to leave those URL's in the sitemap, and if they don't make it into the index while they're paywalled, no harm done; just ask Google to re-crawl the content when you remove the paywall.